# Serve route through subdomain with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, nginx, subdomain

So I have two domains - www.mysite.com and sub.mysite.com

sub.mysite.com is used by a number of legacy apps that can't be updated for varying reasons, and their requests to URLs on that domain need to keep working. However, the code is being moved from the Rails application at sub.mysite.com, and will be integrated into www.mysite.com

The plan, at the moment, is to have the sub.mysite.com content available at www.mysite.com/sub, but I'm at a loss on how to get nginx to render content from www.mysite.com/sub as if it's coming from sub.mysite.com

I've tried a couple of rewrite rules in the nginx config, but they keep redirecting me to www.mysite.com/sub URLs instead of sticking with the sub.mysite.com address.

At the bottom of my nginx config, I've currently got:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name sub.mysite.com;
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://www_server/sub;
  }
}
```

Is what I'm asking for even possible?

Comment: To clarify, I want both www.mysite.com and sub.mysite.com to run off the same Rails application, but for sub.mysite.com to use the "sub" namespace in routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it right what you want is this:

```
location ^~ /sub/ {
    rewrite ^/sub/(.*) http://sub.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Hope it helps.